# Why do I get error on ABS expression when trying to print band footer?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am trying to only print a band footer when two number differ from eachother by more than 2.   I do not care which one if the larger just that the difference is more than 2.   I put into the print when expression a simple formula but I am getting an error.

I have this on my print when expression for a band footer:

```
ABS($F{rop}-$V{Suggest_ROP}) >= 2.0
```

but I am getting an error:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
1. The operator >= is undefined for the argument type(s) Number, double
                value = ABS(((java.lang.Double)field_rop.getValue())-((java.lang.Integer)variable_Suggest_ROP.getValue())) >= 2.0; //$JR_EXPR_ID=15$
                        <------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
2. The operator >= is undefined for the argument type(s) Number, double
                value = ABS(((java.lang.Double)field_rop.getOldValue())-((java.lang.Integer)variable_Suggest_ROP.getOldValue())) >= 2.0; //$JR_EXPR_ID=15$
                        <------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
3. The operator >= is undefined for the argument type(s) Number, double
                value = ABS(((java.lang.Double)field_rop.getValue())-((java.lang.Integer)variable_Suggest_ROP.getEstimatedValue())) >= 2.0; //$JR_EXPR_ID=15$
                        <---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
3 errors

at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:215)
at net.sf.jasperreports.eclipse.builder.JasperReportCompiler.compileReport(JasperReportCompiler.java:195)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler.compileJasperDesign(ReportControler.java:439)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jasper report function [ABS](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/functions/FunctionsReport.pdf) will return a [java.lang.Number](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html), this is an abstract class that do not support any of the arithmetic or logic operator like +, -, <, >, <=

The easiest way is to get the `Integer` or `Double` value from the `Number` (`intValue()`, `doubleValue()` see class methods)

```
ABS($F{rop}-$V{Suggest_ROP}).intValue() >= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:
new Boolean(ABS(new Double("5") - new Double("4")).intValue() > 1 )